# C#. String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing, formatting

I have a string:

```
string date = "2019-06-06T14:31:55.7316366+03:00";
```

and I'm trying to map it to DateTime:

```
var formattedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "dd/MM/yyyy", null)
```

But I have an exception: `"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."`

Comment: The method `ParseExact` has the word exact in it. Your string format need to match.

Comment: Either Use [`Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parse?view=netframework-4.8) or look for the [specific format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: And if you only need the date part. convert it to `DateTime` the use the  `.Date` [property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `TryParseExact` that returns a boolean value indicating if the convert from `string` to `DateTime` is possible on a given `format`. In your case, the format `"o"` is valid because it includes everything you have on your pattern (see the links bellow). For sample:

```
string  date = "2019-06-06T14:31:55.7316366+03:00";
DateTime dateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(date, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
   // it works 
   Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1} ({2}).", date, dateValue, 
                               dateValue.Kind);
}
else
{
   Console.WriteLine("Convertion fails");
}
```

See the working sample: https://dotnetfiddle.net/V8ftPI

You also can use the `ParseExact` like your original sample.

```
var formatedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "o", null);
```

but it can throws an exception if the `date` string is not on a valid pattern.

Check these links on the documentation about the [DateTime.TryParseExact](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.8) and [DateTime formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) and see the valid dateTime formats for C# to extract the format you need.